# Replace & lowercase in Jquery

Tags: jquery, replace, lowercase

I have textbox which on typing the text need to get copy into other textbox and also the spacing between the words need to replace with dash and it should get converted into lower Case.

I have below code but its not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Name').keyup(function(e) {
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    txtVal = txtVal.toLowerCase();
    $('#URL').val(txtVal);
});
```

});

Need HELP, what can be done??

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: `txtVal != taxVal` - you have a typo in the variable name

Comment: ohh shit.. my bad :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After replacing to lower case, replace all `[space]` with `-`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Name').keyup(function(e) {
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    txtVal = txtVal.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-');
    $('#URL').val(txtVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Name" />
<input id="URL" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the whitespace characters with `-`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Name').keyup(function(e) {
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    txtVal = txtVal.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-');
    $('#URL').val(txtVal);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also follow these steps:

1. `toLowerCase()`
2. `split(' ')`
3. `join('-')`

**Code snippets:**

```
txtVal = txtVal.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
```

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ndsLgadf/)